Parse XML to String with <b> tags
I'm only getting value1 when using .findall('string') and rest is ignored. How to get whole value?
xml file input:
<resources>
 <string name="key">value1 <b>value2</b>. value3</string>
</resources>

python code:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
for string in root.findall('string'):
       name = string.get('name')
       value = string.text


You can do it with itertext()
for string in root.findall('string'):
    value = ''.join(string.itertext())
    print(value)

# output:
# value1 value2. value3


An alternative to itertext could be value = ET.tostring(string, method='text')     print(value.decode()). This solution works also, if the tag have tail text, itertext() doesn’t.
